# uA 3 to 12V boost solution?

Tags: boost, low-power

I have an external sensor with a pulse signal. That is the sensor controls a relay/switch. The switch will stay open for the majority of the time (minutes/hours) and once in a while close for a short period (1-1000 ms). I need to supply 12 V to one side of the switch (constantly) in order to catch the asynchronous pulse signal on the other side of the switch once it closes.
[image: sketch]
My device is battery powered and extremely low power oriented. Without this particular type of sensor connected I have about 10 uA idle current. My issue here is that I can not find any good solution to generate the 12 V for the pulse, from my 3.6 V battery, without adding several 100 uA to my idle consumption. Given that I do not consume any current for the vast majority of the time, I'd think that there are better solutions than having a boost module constantly juggle the voltage on a coil to generate those 12V. What am I looking for here?
Currently I'm using this regulator: LT8335EDDB-TRPBF

The energy in each pulse is miniscule. R_tot=40k => 12 V * (12/40k) A * 1/3600 h = 1 uWh.

Comment: Why don't you enable the MAX17223 only when it's required? On the other hand I don't think the 17223 can generate 12 volts can it? It's max limit is 6 volts so, how can you use it?

Comment: Well I'm not sure why your switch needs 12 V, but you should be able to get to much less than several 100 µA to boost your voltage. I was trying to reduce the power needed by a LCD screen which had an internal capacitive boost converter. That needed around 50 µA and with a micropower boost converter it could have been reduced further, but it was too costly in the end. "Micropower boost converter" should give you some results pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @Andyaka Yeah sorry, linked the wrong regulator from my BOM. Corrected it now.

I can't activate it only when needed because I don't know when it's needed. And have no way of knowing.

Comment: So how much current is drawn during the time when the 12 volts needs to be active?

Comment: I'm considering adding a big capacitor and just boost its voltage intermittently. Then I mainly have to deal with the cap leakage. Requires me to control the regulator more smartly, but that could be achieved.

Comment: 220 uF might be a good idea if the current is 0.3 mA <-- is it 0.3 mA? Only activate the regulator when the pulse is present too.

Comment: A good search term would be deep burst mode boost. Different manufacturers call it different things though.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, 40k Ohm, 12V => 0.3 mA.
220 uF wont hold 12 V for 1 sec on 0.3 mA though? I think I need something much bigger?

Comment: @Arsenal and <winny> thanks for suggestion and serch terms
What promted med to write this question was finding too many datasheets that listed "very low Iq, 'just' 2.5 mA"...

Comment: If you reactivate the boost circuit during the pulse it will hold-up the 12 volts much more reliably. How much droop can you tolerate on the 12 volts?

Comment: As I wrote above, I cannot know when the pulse is coming and I don't want to spend energy on idling my regulator in the meantime. The whole point of adding a cap is so that I can shut down my regulator...